# TypeError: is not a constructor [ Webpack Typescript ] import to nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, webstorm

Create themes Node.js Express App from WebStorm 2017.2.5

Javascript Language version ECMAScript 5.1

error with test for webpack@2 and webpack@3

i'am not new obj from import class

I try default export and any

sorry, am little eng skill

```
---------- bin
---------- ctrl/
               main.ts
               control.ts
               interface.ts
---------- dist / main.js
---------- node_modules /
---------- public /
---------- routes / index.js
---------- views  /
---------- app.js
---------- package.json
---------- package-lock.json
---------- webpack.config.js
---------- tsconfig
```

main.ts

```
import {controlA} from from './control';
export default class mainA{
   protected token:string;
   protected controlOBJ:any;
   constructor(_token:string){
     this.token = _token;
     console.log('token'+this.token);
     this.controlOBJ = new controlA(this.token);
   }
}
```

control.ts

```
  export class controlA{
  protected verifyToken:string;
    constructor(_verifyToken:string){
      this.verifyToken = _verifyToken;
      console.log('verifyToken'+this.verifyToken);
    }
  }
```

index.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 //////////////
 var mainA = require('../dist/main).default; 
 new mainA('token');
 // try not work TypeError: mainA is not a constructor

 var mainA = require('../dist/main).mainA;   // try not work 
 new mainA('token');
 // try not work TypeError: mainA is not a constructor

 var mainA = require('../dist/main);
 new mainA.mainA('token');
 // try not work TypeError: mainA is not a constructor

 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './ctrl/main.ts',
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".webpack",".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' , exclude: /node_modules/} //awesome-typescript-loader
      ]
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
}
```

**** test with

```
   module: {
      loaders: [
         { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
      ]
   }
```

not work

```
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
             exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            use:  {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [ 'env' ],
                    plugins: [ 'transform-runtime' ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

not work

```
 var babelOptions = {
     "presets": "es5"
 };
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: babelOptions
            },
            {
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: babelOptions
            }
        ]
    }]
},
```

not work

tsconfig

```
{
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "noImplicitAny": false,
 "noEmitOnError": false,
 "removeComments": true,
 "sourceMap": false,
 "inlineSources": false,
 "preserveConstEnums": true,
 "declaration": false,
 "noEmit": false,
 "noLib": false,
 "allowJs": false
},
 "exclude": [
 "*"
 ],
 "files": [
 "ctrl/interface.ts",
 "ctrl/control.ts",
 "ctrl/main.ts"
 ]
}
```

Please to help me

try for delete line header generator from webpack(dist/main.js) it work 
why? T T

Comment: `var mainA = require('.dist/main').default
new mainA("mytoken")` works fine for me when using your tsconfig.json for compiling

Comment: ups! doesn't indeed work when requiring a module bundled with webpack, as it doesn't seem to expose any modules outside - it's supposed that everything is included in a bundle:(